# I need a low-cost oscilloscope that has event counter capability

Tags: oscilloscope, counter

I need to count the number of microstep pulses (generated by a microcontroller) being applied to a stepper motor controller.

I would like to buy a low-cost (<$500) digital oscilloscope that has a counter function, but I'm not finding one that includes that feature.

Most digital scopes can display frequency in text form, but none that I've found show a "total count" value. I know I could buy a "frequency counter" as a separate instrument, but I'm a hobbyist who doesn't want to spend extra money on another instrument.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to count pulses if the real problem is something else that may be tested without a counter?

Comment: A counter is needed to verify the software is producing the required number of pulses and that the stepper driver module is not missing steps.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel on stepper code when so many CNC shields exist at low cost? Steppers can skip steps even with the right count when you don't know your torque margin

Answer (score 2):

I suggest an inexpensive USB logic analyzer module such as Salae or clones and open-source [Sigrok](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Main_Page) software.

Total cost could be under $15.

Comment: I'll look into that idea. Of course, I want to replace my old analog scope with a new one anyway. Thanks for your response!

Comment: The key word for your shopping (which is off-topic here, of course) is 'MSO' (mixed-signal oscilloscope). Not sure the commercial offerings will do exactly what  you want- typically they are 'closed' firmware upgrades to do more complex things like decoding SPI, I2C etc. protocols.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions?

Use another microcontroller, like an Arduino, with a cheap LCD display, as a counter. It'll cost you less than you'd pay just for the shipping of a counter instrument or an oscilloscope, even if the instrument was free.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I want to replace my old analog scope with a digital one anyway. I could have programmed an Arduino to do the task in the time I've spent researching the topic. Thanks for your response!